# Convert LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity

I have developed a project in Entity Model using LINQ queries, but I should have used stored procedures. Is it possible to convert all the LINQ queries to stored procedures or SQL queries?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: thanks, could you pls tell me how?

Comment: http://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 1):

dc.GetCommand(query).CommandText

And also use LinqPad